# How to load db:seed data into test database automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, seed

I'm attempting to use the new standard way of loading seed data in Rails 2.3.4+, the `db:seed` rake task.

I'm loading constant data, which is required for my application to really function correctly.

What's the best way to get the `db:seed` task to run before the tests, so the data is pre-populated?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The `db:seed` rake task primarily just loads the `db/seeds.rb` script. Therefore just execute that file to load the data.

```
load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"

# or

Rails.application.load_seed
```

Where to place that depends on what testing framework you are using and whether you want it to be loaded before every test or just once at the beginning. You could put it in a `setup` call or in a `test_helper.rb` file.

Comment: I love the simplicity, but for some reason adding this line to my `test_helper.rb` didn't work for me though http://stackoverflow.com/a/1998520/68210 did.

Comment: In newer versions of rails you can do: Rails.application.load_seed

Comment: @Steve thank you - do you know where to put Rails.application.load_seed if one is using rspec/capybarra, for example?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I load seed data quite a bit in my applications because it requires specific data to run and the factory is just too complicated.  I put `Rails.application.load_seed` right under `require 'rspec/rails'`  in my rails_helper file.  If you are using database_cleaner gem - it will require a little tweaking to make sure you don't lose your seed data after each test and you can find that in the documentation of the gem it self

Comment: In Rails 5.x I added this to `test/test_helper.rb` after the existing `require 'rails/test_help'` line

Answer (score 87):

I'd say it should be

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare => :environment do
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Because db:test:load is not executed if you have config.active_record.schema_format = :sql (db:test:clone_structure is)

Comment: Running rake with `--trace` helped me understand how this works.

Comment: @BookOfGreg I have it in lib/tasks/test_seed.rake that I created myself

Comment: Why not run it in db:test:prepare?

Comment: Once I figured out that (a) the rake code can go in lib/tasks/test_seed.rake and (b) it gets run AFTER the standard `rake db:test:prepare task` has completed, this is the winning approach for me.

Comment: Why not just this?  `task 'db:test:prepare' => 'db:seed'`

Comment: This method was working for me just fine all the way through Rails 4.0.0.rc1, but isn't in Rails 4.0.0 (final). Anyone know a fix? Doing a 'rake test --trace' shows that db:seed is being invoked, but my factory_girl factories can't locate the seed data. Inspecting the test DB shows that it's empty, as well!

Comment: For Rails 4.0.0 final add `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['test'])` before `Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke`

Comment: Note that if any fixture files exist for your models, rails will delete existing data in the table (loaded from seeds.rb or otherwise) for that model and replace it with the YML data before running your tests.  It does this even if the YML file is empty.

Comment: @CarsonReinke - because then the environment when `db:seed` runs is `development`... weirdly.

Comment: @EugeneBolshakov - actually, same issue with your solution... environment was `development` when `seeds.rb` runs. (Rails 3.2.13 at least)

Answer (score 17):

Putting something like this in lib/tasks/test_seed.rake should invoke the seed task after db:test:load:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :load => :environment do
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 17):

I believe [Steve's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically#comment25538690_1574848) above should be the correct answer. You can use `Rails.application.load_seed` to load seed data into your test envoironment. However, when and how often this data is loaded depends on a few things:

## Using Minitest

There is no convenient way to run this file once before all tests (see [this Github issue](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/61)). You'll need to load the data once before each test, likely in the setup method of your test files:

```
# test/models/my_model_test.rb
class LevelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end

  # tests here...

end
```

## Using RSpec

Use RSpec's `before(:all)` method to load seed data for all test for this model:

```
describe MyModel do
  before(:all) do
  Rails.application.load_seed
end

describe "my model..." do
  # your tests here
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Best answer so far

Comment: I do something similar, except that I'm invoking it in `before(:suite)` instead of `before(:all)`.  Posted a separate answer to include formatted code.

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least for MiniTest. Adding it to `test_helper.rb` results in the seeds file being run multiple times, potentially resulting in errors due to duplicate keys.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Matt's answer, if taking that sort of route, I recommend calling `Rails.application.load_seed` in a `before(:suite)` block in `rspec_helper.rb` rather than in a `before(:all)` block in any file.  That way the seeding code is invoked only once for the entire test suite rather than once for each group of tests.

rspec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.before(:suite) do
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

We're invoking db:seed as a part of db:test:prepare, with:

`Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke`

That way, the seed data is loaded once for the entire test run, and not once per test class.

Comment: Did you create a new db:test:prepare task to do that? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 3):

Adding `Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke` to the `db:test:prepare` rake task did not work for me. If I prepared the database with `rake db:test:prepare`, and then entered the console within the test environment, all my seeds were there. However, the seeds did not persist between my tests.

Adding `load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"` to my setup method worked fine, though.

I would love to get these seeds to load automatically and persist, but I haven't found a way to do that yet!

Answer (score 3):

For those using seedbank, it changes how seeds are loaded, so you probably can't/don't want to use the `load ...` solution provided here.

And just putting `Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke` into test_helper resulted in:

```
Don't know how to build task 'db:seed' (RuntimeError)
```

But when we added load_tasks before that, it worked:

```
MyApp::Application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
```