# In rails 3, how can I ensure enum tables are loaded into the test database before models load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, fixtures

Using ActiveSupport::TestCase. I think that's the old Test::Unit.

I have several tables that represent enumerated values. These never change and I would like to use their data in class scope for activerecord finders.

This causes a problem with tests because model classes load before fixtures and fixtures are rolled back between tests. I can't copy the enum tables into a fixture because the data will not yet be loaded when models load.

Is there a way to bring the test database to an initial state before models load and before the fixture transaction begins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining a setup method for your tests?

Or seeding the database using db/seeds.rb?

Comment: db/seeds.rb doesn't seem to load when tests are run. If I load it manually it gets deleted when tests start. Where can I hook into the test setup to seed the db? The normal setup that runs before each test won't work. It needs to run once before all tests.

Comment: For seeding, see the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898782/prevent-rails-test-from-deleting-seed-data. In particular check out the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If they never ever change you could put the create statements directly into your migrations so they are created when the tables are rebuilt - seems a bit messy to be honest though but should work.

Comment: Migrations aren't run to start a test run. The test schema is created from db/schema.rb, a generated file. Come to think about it, I have the same problem with db views in tests since views aren't cloned to db/schema.rb. If I could set what goes into db/schema.rb I could solve both problems, but perhaps there is a better way.