# Seed data during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have huge number of constants to be used during testing which I have in seed. So how is it possible to run seed during testing as well specially rspec/cucumber. It's been mentioned that I should better use fabricator or factory girl to populate the data. But I have huge number of constants, so I will have to manually add them to factory(that will be tedius). Plus I have lots of associated data. So is it a good option? Suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just drop them in spec_helper.rb? I don't do rspec, but that's how I'd go about it.

Comment: Actually it's not just some constants but objects, around 100 of them

Comment: awesome answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898782/prevent-rails-test-from-deleting-seed-data