# Loading Mongoid seed data automatically before Rspec runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mongoid, mongodb

Someone asked this question here:

[How to load db:seed data into test database automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically)

But their solution only works if you are going to run db:test:prepare which depends on a schema to load.  Mongoid doesn't have a schema file, and db:test:prepare doesn't do anything and so this is not working.  Is there another strategy that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a FYI, I figured out a way to meet my requirements.  I set up a database called seed like so in mongoid.yml:

```
 databases:
    seeds:
      database: seeds_db
      host: localhost
      port: 27018
```

Then in my model I just have the datase use seeds like:

```
class SeededData
  include Mongoid::Document
    set_database :seeds
```

This actually works great because production, test, and development are all pulling from the seed database, which is what I want.  And I'm never vacuuming out the data when running tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question here. I think that especially the last answer would help you :

[How to load db:seed data into test database automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically)

Comment: Yeah that was the question I referenced in my post.  But if I put Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke in my Rakefile it still isn't getting invoked.  Maybe because I'm using Mongoid and so rake it being skipped?