# Seeding test database in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just starting to implement some tests for my work in progress rails app. I have some dependencies (the main one being devise for user management) which will require me to have a user already registered.

I have these items set up in my `db/seeds.rb` file.

I have found some information from [this article](http://pathfindersoftware.com/2010/01/rubyrails-loading-seed-data-for-tests/), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically/12487968#12487968) but they relate to earlier versions of rails.

I created a `test_seeds.rake` file as suggested by one of the questions, but it didn't seem to get called when I run

```
rake tests
```

so I'm working on the theory that it wasn't just the test folder structure that changed as part of rails 4.

Can anyone provide any rails 4 guidance on how to achieve this?

Thanks
Jane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418819/steve)'s comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically/12487968) I discovered

```
Rails.application.load_seed
```

which I've implemented in the following method in my `test/test_helper.rb` file as follows:

```
  def set_up
    Rails.application.load_seed 
  end
```

which does what I need. I'm unsure if this is a Rails 4 way of doing it though.

Comment: I'm using RSpec and put this in spec/rails_helper.rb after all of the requires statements.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank).

It allows you to specify separate seed files.

- Seed files that need to be run in every environment.
- Seed files that only need to be run in development, test or production.
- Seed files that need to be run in certain custom situations.

I think that seedbank overrides the `rake db:setup` task, and that this in turn is run by `rake tests`. But you would have to test that to make sure.