# How best to create table on initialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Happy New Year everyone.

In my Rails 4 application I have a table `plans` containing the records for the plans that a `user` can subscribe to.

It is absolutely paramount for the app that this table is populated at *any* time, in development, test, and production mode. Otherwise the app will not work.

What is the best way to create those records?

Should I put a `create` method into an initializer? Or set up a rake task and run it manually whenever I restart the server (sounds a bit cumbersome, though)?

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Rails has a 'seeds' feature that should be used for seeding a database with initial data. 
It's a really simple feature: just fill up `db/seeds.rb` with some Ruby code, and run `rake db:seed`

source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

If you want to use data in your test environment, you might also be interested in using fixtures for your `plans`. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

Comment: Sounds good and I've just tested it. Problem is I have to run `rake db:seed` manually every time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'every time'. Once the data is seeded, why do you want to run the seeds again?

Comment: For example, every time I run my test suite using the `rspec` command. I wouldn't want to type `rake db:seed` every time before I run a test.

Comment: You can call 'Rails.application.load_seed' inside your test. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically

Comment: OK, I actually ended up creating the table in an initializer which works very well for me and feels good too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you might also be interested in using fixtures for your plans. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures